# How do two charged insulating spheres separated by a finite distance between their centres interact?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

> [image: 1]

I was solving problems of electrostatics from *Pathfinder for Olympiad and JEE Advanced Physics* by Arvind Tiwari and Sachin Singh when I encountered this problem. I can understand that the conducting spheres will have the charge on their surface rearranged as the electrons are free to move in them. Thus they will have an orientation where the unlike charges will come to closer hemispheres and show maximum attraction while like charges will move to the alternate hemisphere, showing minimum repulsion.

I also thought that this rearrangement will not be possible in insulating spheres as how on the earth the charges gonna dislocate! So I was sure that the answer would be (b). But to my surprise, its (d). Please guide me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

None of conclusions (a) or (b) or (c) or (d) can be certainly drawn. Here is why.

Let's consider first conducting then insulating spheres.

1. Conducting spheres with like charges:

$(+ \;\; \; )$  $(\;\; \;+)\;\;\;\;$   hence $F_c > F_m$.

2. Conducting spheres with unlike charges:

$(\;\; \; +)$  $(- \;\; \;)\;\;\;\;$   hence $F_c < F_m$.

Now let's turn to insulating spheres. For an insulator the charge might be anywhere and it will stay wherever it happens to be.

3. Insulating spheres with like charges:

could be $(+ \;\; \; )$  $(\;\; \;+)\;\;\;\;$ or $(\;\; \; +)$  $(+ \;\; \;)\;\;\;\;$
or $(\;+\;)$  $(\;+ \;)\;\;\;\;$ so $F_c$ could be greater than or less than or equal to $F_m$.

4. Insulating spheres with unlike charges:

could be $(+ \;\; \; )$  $(\;\; \;-)\;\;\;\;$ or $(\;\; \; +)$  $(- \;\; \;)\;\;\;\;$ or $(\;+\;)$  $(\;- \;)\;\;\;\;$ so $F_c$ could be greater than or less than or equal to $F_m$.

Thus conclusion (d) is *possible* for all materials, but not *guaranteed* for all materials. And in case (b) the statement should be that the spheres *could be* conducting, but we cannot know that for sure. This is assuming the spheres simply stay in place at their respective locations, without rotating.

If, on the other hand, the spheres are each free to rotate, then they will rotate to the cases

$(+ \;\; \; )$  $(\;\; \;+)\;\;\;\;$

and

$(\;\; \; +)$ $(- \;\; \; )$

so then we will find conclusion (d) for any materials. Perhaps that is what the original setter of the question had in mind.

Comment: Hey, it just ticked me... but what about uniformly distributed charge on insulating spheres? How can they be  reasoned out? 'Cause the rotation in them will not be able to minimise or maximize anything

Comment: @SteelCubes uniform on (or in) a sphere will produce a field outside that is the same as the one which would be produced by a point charge at the centre of the sphere. So the question becomes, how does the other sphere (with its distributed charge) interact with that field? I don't have time to calculate this now. You could try considering the case of a shell of charge; that will tell you all you need to know. My hunch is that answer is equiv to a point charge but I'm not certain.

Comment: Sir, I've been getting the same hunches. Though the answer given in the question may seem absurd, this book is known for extremely tricky conceptual problems. And I am absolutely certain that we must be missing something in the consideration of the situation. Finding this missing piece of information was my motive behind asking this question up here.

Answer (score 0):

Both for conductors and insulators like charges effectively move to a larger distance and unlike charges to a smaller one. In both case this is due to polarization of the spheres. Therefore d) is the correct answer.

Comment: Do you have any comments on the fact this is opposite to what Andrew Steane has answered?

Comment: I assume that the charge is spherically distributed on the spheres if there is no interaction. Otherwise the calculation would be simply wrong for the case of the insulator.